# Unable to hide PHP Intl error from front end

Tags: wordpress, errorhandling

On my Wordpress site CiviCrm events pages are displaying the following message on the front end:

> Missing PHP INTL extension As this system does not include the PHP
> intl extension, CiviCRM has fallen back onto a slightly less accurate
> and deprecated method to format money

My hosting provider doesn't support PHP Intl which is not a big deal as we're not collecting money on the site. How can I get rid of this error message? Preface that I am a total noob, and really need explicit instructions on where to place code etc. TIA

Comment: Even though Intl is not required now, if your hosting provider can't/won't support that then see this as a warning to move to a more capable hoster before their lack of support becomes critical to you.  If the next release makes it (or any other php module) mandatory and you don't notice before upgrading then you're dead in the water.  Good hosting for CiviCRM for small sites does not have to be expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Aidan, unfortunately my company is a small fish in a very big corporate pond. Corporate IT have said we must use this particular hosting provider.

Comment: Ok, that's not a fun place to be. But even corporate IT should understand 'does not meet requirements'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that message could be disabled from the Admin UI, but i believe you can disable it with deleting [this line](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1e5f06c8283ebad23974bb4c551386278176f004/CRM/Utils/Money.php#L328) or commenting that out (put `//` to the beginning to the line).

This file has to be located somewhere on the server under the `CRM/Utils` directory. (i believe your hosting provider can help you locating it) Before editing it, create a backup from the file.

Overwriting a crm-core file is not a good solution because if you deploy a new version of CRM, your changes might be overwritten, so you have to apply the patch again.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.